Foundry Solidity Error: panic: array out-of-bounds access (0x32) while testing a batch mint function
I'm writing foundry tests for a function which batch mints erc1155 tokens for the users, but I'm getting a panic revert.
The function I'm testing:
    function mintBatch(
        address to_,
        uint256[] calldata tokenIds_,
        uint256[] calldata amounts_,
        bytes calldata data_
    ) external payable {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenIds_.length; i++) {
            Work storage work = works[tokenIds_[i]];
            FEE_MANAGER.collectMintFee{value: msg.value}(
                this, tokenIds_[i], amounts_[i], msg.sender, address(0), work.strategy
            );
        }

        _batchMint(to_, tokenIds_, amounts_, data_);
    }

The foundry test I wrote:
    function test_batchMint() public {
        uint[] memory tokenIds = new uint[](2);
        tokenIds[1] = 1;
        tokenIds[2] = 2;
        uint[] memory tokenAmts = new uint[](2);
        tokenAmts[1] = 1;
        tokenAmts[2] = 1;
        edition.mintBatch{value: 0.0106 ether}(address(1), tokenIds, tokenAmts, new bytes(0));
        assertEq(edition.totalSupply(1), 1);
        assertEq(edition.totalSupply(2), 1);
    }

The error I'm getting, which I run forge test --mt test_batchMint:
Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/editions/Edition.t.sol:EditionTest
[FAIL. Reason: panic: array out-of-bounds access (0x32)] test_batchMint() (gas: 424)

Encountered a total of 1 failing tests, 0 tests succeeded

Pls help me, I tried finding a solution but got none, pls guide me about what's wrong I'm doing, Is I am inputting arrays correctly? Thanks!

I think the problem is here:
    uint[] memory tokenIds = new uint[](2);
    tokenIds[1] = 1;
    tokenIds[2] = 2;
    uint[] memory tokenAmts = new uint[](2);
    tokenAmts[1] = 1;
    tokenAmts[2] = 1;

You are defining an array of length 2 but you are trying to access the indexes 1 and 2 which, instead, should be 0 and 1. Because the index starts from 0. So the correct way would be:
    uint[] memory tokenIds = new uint[](2);
    tokenIds[0] = 1;
    tokenIds[1] = 2;
    uint[] memory tokenAmts = new uint[](2);
    tokenAmts[0] = 1;
    tokenAmts[1] = 1;


Good Catch. Thanks!
